# Why my AsyncTask is not executing during application start?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts

I need to insert all phone book **contacts** data in my **local application sqlite database on Application startup.** For this i have implemented a class named `LoadContacts.java` which must `extends Application class`. Also, i have multiple classes that must be extending Application class for which i am sub classing these classes from one another.

These multiple classes are `GenerateFacebookSignature extends Application`, `VolleyAppController extends GenerateFacebookSignature`, `SessionManagement extends VolleyAppController` & `LoadContacts extends SessionManagement`. This is my class hierarchy.

The Async Task written inside LoadContacts.java is not executing because when i have checked attaching debugger in DatabaseHelper class it is returning null cursor.

This is the code for my LoadContacts.java.

```
public class LoadContacts extends SessionManagement {
    Context context;
    Uri contactsUri, contactsDataUri;
    Cursor contactsCursor, contactsDataCursor, birthDayCursor;
    String contactId;
    GetAllPhoneBookContacts getAllPhoneBookContacts;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    public LoadContacts(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        getAllPhoneBookContacts = new GetAllPhoneBookContacts();
        getAllPhoneBookContacts.execute();
    }

    public class GetAllPhoneBookContacts extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");
            if (contactsCursor != null && contactsCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                if (contactsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        contactId = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));

                        contactsDataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                        contactsDataCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsDataUri, null, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, null);

                        String displayName = "";
                        String birthday = "";

                        if (contactsDataCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            displayName = contactsDataCursor.getString(contactsDataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            birthDayCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.DATA }, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= '" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY, null, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
                            if (birthDayCursor != null) {
                                if (birthDayCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                                    while (birthDayCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                        birthday = birthDayCursor.getString(0);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            do {
                            }
                            while (contactsDataCursor.moveToNext());

                                databaseHelper.insertIntoContacts(contactId, displayName, birthday);
                        }
                    }
                    while (contactsCursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please check that what i am doing wrong or **why the contacts are not inserting in my local sqlite database.** If there is a need of any other code i am ready to post it. Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: In Manifest file, which class you have define as application?

Comment: Add your DatabaseHelper class.

Comment: I am adding SessionManagement in my Manifest file.

Comment: @Ankit i am unable to post whole database class but i will post the Contacts table structure and the method where i am getting the contacts data. See the edits above.

Comment: @AshishKumarGupta just start asynkTask inside `SessionManagement` `onCreate method`.

Comment: As LoadContact onCreate will never called.

Answer (score 1):

if `SessionManagement`you have define in your Manifest file as an application class. Then you must start asyncTask in sessionManagement onCreate Method.

Comment: sorry i mean i am trying your way.

Comment: I need an advice of yours, could you please help me.

Comment: when i have not implemented LoadContacts.java i have Application classes hierarchy as GenerateFacebookSignature extends Application, VolleyAppController extends GenerateFacebookSignature, SessionManagement extends VolleyAppController & i have defined VolleyAppController in my manifest file & everything is working fine. Now which class is most suitable to write async task so that it will execute properly.

Comment: see which class you have defined in your Manifest that will be your application class. Then inside onCreate method super.onCreate() will called parent onCreate method. but it will never called a child onCreate method. Got it?

Comment: sorry i am unable to clearly understand your point & i have not an overriden method onCreate in any of the three Application classes, then in which class i have to implement the AsyncTask. Can u please give some link or code example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80851/discussion-between-praveen-sharma-and-ashish-kumar-gupta).